# Monitoring Web Page Contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web

I need to develop a web application which should monitor another website pages. (i.e) To check whether the contents are getting updated timely or not. For example some contents needs to be updated every 5 minute, some needs to be updated every 1 hour,  etc.,

My current idea is to download the required pages using wget and generate a complete json file in the backend. Then my application will download the json via ajax call and based on that I will do some alerting.

My question is, Is this the right way? Or any other better approaches already there to acheive this.

Comment: Did you look for existing monitoring tools? Google Analytics, Azure Insights, etc.

Comment: I want to do particular content check also. For example inside some div I need to check the content.

Comment: And what if you add a little JS script who detects the content you want to check, and send its state to a web service of your own? This way you don't have to download all web page, and only check the data in you web service

Comment: The final server where I am going to deploy the application will not have internet connection. It's an internal server. So I will write the back end script as I mentioned above in a server which has internet connection. Then I will download that file via sftp from the internal server.

Answer (score 0):

> Try using a web-scraper.

First: If the website what you are monitoring does not know about your actions you might take in consideration legal issues.

Second: Yes you can do that if the website is plain html with low programming skills using node with dependencies request and cheerio.
Here is a basic example of how you can parse news url's on the independent website:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

//proxy from http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/
var __proxyArray =["http://85.143.164.100:81", "http://111.13.143.141:8080", "http://176.9.60.39:3128" ];

var randomProxy = function (){
  var low = 0, high = __proxyArray.length;
  var shuffled = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
  return __proxyArray[shuffled].uri ;
};

var options = {
    uri:"http://www.independent.co.uk/",
    proxy: randomProxy(),
    headers: {
              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36'
            }
    };
  console.log("start");
request(options, function(err, res, body){
  if(err || res.statusCode != 200) {
    callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
    return;
  }
  //entire content
  var xXx = JSON.stringify(body);
  console.log(xXx);

  //parsing with regex, you can use jquery in node as well
  var rePattern = new RegExp(/(?=<a href="\/news)(?:\s*)(.*?)(?:\s*)(?=<\/a>)/g);
  var newsMatches = body.match(rePattern);


  for (var i=0; i<newsMatches.length; i++){
    //continue parsing url's pages
    console.log(newsMatches[i]);
  }

});
```

If is an app or a lot of async content loaded with ajax You might need to take a look at phantom.js. In both cases you will need to take care of number of requests accepted by the server hosting the website, you might end up with your IP banned, you can find a lot of proxy lists out there.

It may not be helpful for you, but this is the only way you can go trow a entire website (it's not fair to use user browser to parse all website pages and send back to your recorder).

Cheers.

Comment: The final server where I am going to deploy the application will not have internet connection. It's an internal server. So I will write a back end bash script in a server which has internet connection and generates a json file. Then I will download that file via sftp from the internal server which will be used by the application. Is this ok?